# How to load caffe models in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opencv, image-processing, caffe

When I run this code below (C# form app), It gives me an error and it says;
-- "OpenCvSharp.OpenCVException: 'FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "/age_deploy.prototxt"
[Full error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDopj.png)

I have downloaded the model files but don't know how to load them in c# Can anybody please help me?

Code

```
        const string faceProto = "models/deploy.prototxt";
        const string faceModel = "models/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000_fp16.caffemodel";
        const string ageProto = @"/age_deploy.prototxt";
        const string ageModel = @"models/age_net.caffemodel";
        const string genderProto = @"models/gender_deploy.prototxt";
        const string genderModel = @"models/gender_net.caffemodel";
        _ageNet = CvDnn.ReadNetFromCaffe(ageProto, ageModel);
        _genderNet = CvDnn.ReadNetFromCaffe(genderProto, genderModel);
        _faceNet = CvDnn.ReadNetFromCaffe(faceProto, faceModel);
```

Comment: what type of project are you trying to run this under?  test?  console?  web?

Comment: C# win form with opencvsharp library

Comment: do you have a file in that path specified with that name?...it's telling you the path its expecting

Comment: Can you please check this link out below.  I fix it but there's another problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67662723/face-detection-detects-everything-in-frame-and-gives-error